# Android mobile socket does not connect with Computer Java Server?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp, serversocket

My client application on android phone does not connect with java server on pc.
My java server is properly working but when I connect android client with java server, client side socket throw IOException.
I performed debugging, and found that when the wifi is off, it throws exception immediately but when wifi is available then it waits for some time and then throws IOException.

I have built more than 10 client programs in different ways but every program whether its client or server crashes when i try it in android.

What's the problem in client and can we really connect android to pc through sockets and is there any other way to establish tcp/ip connection between android mobile and pc?

**Client Code:**

```
package com.example.androidclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Client extends Activity {

// socket programming connection oriented stuff declaration
private Socket clientSocket;
private DataOutputStream outToServer;

private Button connect;
private EditText sendMessage;
private TextView sentMessage;

private String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bConnect);
    sendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    sentMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            message = sendMessage.getText().toString();
            new Thread( new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    message = "Rashid";
                    try {
                        clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.56.1"), 5555);
//Above line of code is the cause of exception.
                        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                        outToServer.writeBytes(message);

                        outToServer.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        message = "ErrorHE";
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        message = "ErrorIO";
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            sentMessage.setText(message);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**STACK TRACE:**

06-17 10:49:05.407: W/System.err(15780): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 5555) after 90000ms

06-17 10:49:05.412: W/System.err(15780):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:176)

06-17 10:49:05.414: W/System.err(15780):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)

06-17 10:49:05.417: W/System.err(15780):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)

06-17 10:49:05.421: W/System.err(15780):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

06-17 10:49:05.424: W/System.err(15780):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:575)

06-17 10:49:05.427: W/System.err(15780):    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:228)

06-17 10:49:05.430: W/System.err(15780):    at com.example.androidclient.Client$1$1.run(Client.java:55)

06-17 10:49:05.433: W/System.err(15780):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

Attached Images:
I'm new user so i can't upload images yet that's  why I'm attaching link of stack trace images.[StackTrace](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/475ao4657q3ub1b/AADXcxg6-YQ31id2Nb4XNbqha)

Comment: What do you mean with internet connection? I know of wifi and 3G.

Comment: I'm talking about Wifi

Comment: An ioexception is something different then a crash. Please explain what/where exactly happens on which line. As your code looks ok  you should provide more info. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Here is the Stack Trace

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/475ao4657q3ub1b/AADXcxg6-YQ31id2Nb4XNbqha

Comment: Please post the stacktrace here. Well the relevant part only.

Comment: As I'm new user I'm not allowed to post images that's why I have attached dropbox link of Stack Trace image

Comment: If you are asked to post the logcat or stacktrace then you are supposed to post it as text. Copy and paste.